# How do I flush in RISC-V assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to translate
`while ((getchar()) != '\n');`
into assembly but am finding it difficult.

Comment: Making asm code that interoperates with C stdio is hard as it depends on the (unspecified) internal details of how the C std library is implemented.  It will be different on different operating systems.

Comment: @ChrisDodd  The C library has been standard for decades. It's behavior is very well documented. So well documented that the C++ standard itself adopts the C standard.

Comment: I'm thinking of just calling my assembly version of scan user input, ecall, again to clear the buffer.

Comment: @Nole, the interface and behavior of the library is well-defined, of course, but the details of each implementation vary. When getchar is implemented as a macro, it makes use of those internal details. I think that's what Chris was referring to.

Comment: @NoleKsum: While the behavior and interface is well documented, the internals are not and differ between systems.  Generally a `FILE` will contain a buffer, some pointers, and some flags, but the details are not part of the spec.  BSD libc and GNU libc are different and Windows is different again.

Comment: The title mentions "flush" (typical for output streams), the code sample calls `getchar` (typical for input streams); that does not match. It's also unclear what part of the code is giving you trouble. Making a `while` loop? Comparing with newline? Calling `getchar()`? Getting the return value from `getchar()`? Or is your intention to write your own I/O read operation from scratch? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Are you asking how to consume all unread input out to the end of a line?  As in [How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7898215) (which also checks for EOF).  Apparently on some systems, `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` also works, at least to discard the actual input buffer, not necessarily to read any more bytes that user-space hasn't got from the kernel yet.  Or use `scanf("%*[^\n]");`.  Or as Steve Summit's answer says, if you need this, that's probably a design problem and you should really try to avoid needing this in the first place.

Comment: A compiler can turn any of these into RISC-V asm for you.

Answer (score 2):

You would use something like this:

```s
        li      s0, 10
again:
        call    getchar
        bne     a0, s0,again
```

Comment: `getchar` is generally a C macro -- to have a function, you need `fgetc` instead, but how to  get `stdin` in asm code is not specified -- it may be a macro too.

Comment: `getchar is generally a C macro` - I can see `getchar@@GLIBC_2.2.5` defined on `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`